# Splitting strings using Ruby ignoring certain characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to split a string and counts the number os words using Ruby but I want ignore special characters.

For example, in this string "Hello, my name is Hugo ..." I'm splitting it by spaces but the last ... should't counts because it isn't a word.

I'm using `string.inner_text.split(' ').length`. How can I specify that special characters (such as ... ? ! etc.) when separated from the text by spaces are not counted?

Thank you to everyone,
Kind Regards,
Hugo

Answer (score 6):

```
 "Hello, my name is não ...".scan /[^*!@%\^\s\.]+/
 # => ["Hello,", "my", "name", "is", "não"]
```

`/[^*!@%\^]+/` will match anything other than `*!@%\^`. You can add more to this list which need not be matched

Comment: Arf, you're too quick this morning!

Comment: It works but only for non-portuguese words. With accents, like "não", "é", etc. it removes the accented letter and split the word: "não" appears as "n" "o".

Answer (score 1):

this is part answer, part response to @Neo's answer: why not use proper tools for the job?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html says:

> POSIX bracket expressions are also similar to character classes. They provide a portable alternative to the above, with the added benefit that they encompass non-ASCII characters. For instance, /\d/ matches only the ASCII decimal digits (0-9); whereas /[[:digit:]]/ matches any character in the Unicode Nd category.
>
> - /[[:alnum:]]/ - Alphabetic and numeric character
> - /[[:alpha:]]/ - Alphabetic character
> - ...
>
> Ruby also supports the following non-POSIX character classes:
>
> - /[[:word:]]/ - A character in one of the following Unicode general categories Letter, Mark, Number, Connector_Punctuation

you want words, use `str.scan /[[:word:]]+/`